# Subscribe method don't react to changes [Angular 2]

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I've got the method in my app.component that changes languages in my LangService. When the change occurs the LangService should then response with Observable object to all my other components as I have subscribed to changes in all my components. Unfortunately, it's not happening. It only response to the app.component that called the function for changing the language. I'm not sure where I have made a mistake. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the whole concept as I'm new to Angular.

Here is the code:

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">                                           
        {{ title }}
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li *ngFor="let lang of langs">
            <a (click)="changeLanguage(lang)">
              {{ lang }}
            </a>  
          </li>
        </ol>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import './rxjs-operators';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router'; 
import { LangService } from './lang.service';
import { NotesComponent } from './notes/notes.component';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [NotesComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [LangService]
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = " Note App for BSC-Ideas";
  langs :Array<string> = ['EN', 'CZ'];

  constructor(
    private _langService :LangService
  ) {
    this._langService.activeLang$.subscribe(
      success => console.log('done') // It works here
    );
  } 

  changeLanguage(lang :string) :void{
    this._langService.changeLanguage(lang);
  }

}
```

some other.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LangService } from '../lang.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'all-notes',
  templateUrl: 'notes.component.html',
  providers: [NoteService, LangService]
})
export class NotesComponent implements OnInit {

  mode = 'Observable';

  constructor(private _langService :LangService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updatePhrases(this.postPhrases);

    this._langService.getUpdates().subscribe(
      success => console.log('is working') //Doesn't work here
    );
  }

}
```

LangService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class LangService {
  activeLang = 'EN';
  private activeLangSubject = new Subject<string>();
  activeLang$ = this.activeLangSubject.asObservable();

  getUpdates() :Observable<Object>{
    return this.activeLang$.map(
      response => response || {}
    );
  }

  changeLanguage(lang :string){
    if(lang == 'EN' || lang == 'CZ'){
      this.activeLang = lang;
      this.activeLangSubject.next(lang);
    }
  }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you provide `LangService` on each component, each component will get its own instance.

Instead provide it only once at the root component or `bootstrap(AppComponent, [LangService])`

If you use `RC.5` add it to `providers: [LangService]` of the `@NgModule()` then it will become a global service automaticall (except when it's a lazy loaded module, then you need to use `forRoot()`)

Comment: Thank you. One more question. If I add it to the bootstrap I don't need to add it as a provider to every component?

Comment: Angulars DI creates an instance for every provider. When a component has a dependency DI starts looking at providers of this component, then parent components and so up to `bootstrap()`. The instance of the first provider it find gets passed to the constructor. This way you can control the scope of your services. If you want a single instance shared, then you need to provide it **exactly once** at the root (`AppComponent` or `bootstrap()`)

Comment: I have the same problem. Should I remove service's import from component ? How to call service in this case ?

Comment: I think it's better to create a new question with the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I have created new question, pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999176/angular-2-how-to-share-one-service-among-several-components

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to share the instance of `LangService` in all of your component. To do so only provide `LangService` in top level component. In your case probably app.component.ts

You can go through [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)  article to understand dependency injection and provider in detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see the mistakes now.