# Angular 2: how to share one service among several components?

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I have some service in my angular application like this to store the status of user:

```
public activeUser = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

I do the follow:

Go to the component A and in constructor I have subscribed on this Subject (auth is service, which has been imported):

```
    this.auth.activeUser.subscribe((status) => {
        console.log("subscribe >>>", status);
        this.isAuth = status;
    });
```

In another method of this components I do this:

```
this.auth.activeUser.next(true);
```

if user login successfully, and set false if some troubles.

Greate, it works, I have got console output.

But I have another component, which must use `activeUser` status. In this component I imported service and do the follow:

```
ngOnInit() { 
       this.auth.activeUser.subscribe(
          (userStatus:boolean) => {
              this.isAuth = userStatus;
              console.log("this is foo HomeComponent", this.isAuth);
          }
      );
      console.log("home activeUser", this.auth.activeUser);
  }
```

I consider that when in first component `Subject` gets `next(true)` or `next(false)` I have to see `this is foo HomeComponent`in console, but it's not true.

I found this answer 
[Subscribe method don't react to changes [Angular 2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39166063/subscribe-method-dont-react-to-changes-angular-2)

and according to it I have done the follow:

1. Go to app.module.ts
2. Imported service
3. Add service to providers[]

Hmmm, I hoped that my problem will be soled. But no.
I returned to my second component and removed the import with service. But now I can't compile the code:

```
this.auth.activeUser.subscribe
```

where `auth` is injected service.
I have even restarted webpack, but anyway fails.
Thanks you for help.

Full second component is there:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "../../platform/auth.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


@Component({
    selector: 'home-page',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    styleUrls:['home.component.scss']

})

export class HomeComponent  implements OnInit {
    public isAuth: boolean;
    constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
        this.isAuth = true;
    }

   ngOnInit() { 
       this.auth.activeUser.subscribe(
          (userStatus:boolean) => {
              this.isAuth = userStatus;
              console.log("this is foo HomeComponent", this.isAuth);
          }
      );
      console.log("home activeUser", this.auth.activeUser);
  }

}
```

My app.module.ts

```
 import {AuthService} from "./platform/auth.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        // CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        routing,
        ModalModule,
        NgbModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],

    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders, AuthService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {


    public activeUser = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor(private http: Http, private interaction:InteractionService) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show where you provide the service and what components are involved.

Comment: I have updated question, pls

Comment: Where did you provide the service? Where did you add it to `providers: []`?

Comment: I have added app.module.ts

Comment: Hard to tell. How does the service look like?

Comment: I have added service, pls

Comment: If I remove import with service from component, then how should I call activeUser form service ? Should I omit injection of service ? or if I have added AuthService to app.module.ts it should be known ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125504/discussion-between-eugene-shmorgun-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Nobody said you should remove an import.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. You **definitly** need to import the service to every file where you use `AuthService` in **any way** and you need to add it to `providers: []` of `@NgModule()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a ReplaySubject. This will replay the last event that was on the stream when a new consumer subscribes. Create one like this:

```
   // 1 is the amount of events to replay when subscribed
   new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
```

You can use it the same way you used the `BehaviourSubject`

Comment: Can you check in what order the .subscribe() calls and the .next() call are happening, by logging before you subscribe and before you call .next?